# swift tab bar trying to show login view controller on certain pages

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have just switched my applications navigation into tab bar.

Now I wonder how I can show a login VC when I click on certain tabs.

Before I just made a performSegueWithIdentifier() if the user was not logged in. But how can I do this with a navigation bar bar controller? I dont want the login VC to be displayed as an item in the navigation bar, I only want to show it if the user is not logged in and clicks on a certain tab item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the tab bar controller's view controllers check whether the user is already logged in and if it is required -- present a login few controller if needed, say modally.

Comment: So you mean that I can check if a "session" exist in viewDidLoad() in the VC that I am trying to enter? And if not just fire a segue to a modal screen.

Comment: Exactly. I would put these checks in `viewWillAppear()` since you might want to check for login every time the view comes on screen. That way, if the user logs out and the view is not unloaded, you make your the login scene appears next time the user taps on the tab.